# I am using paypal for credit card payment, if the users click the confirm button twice, two requests are coming back

Tags: paypal, struts-1

From my java web application, I am redirecting to paypal payment gateway page for credit card payment and after successful verification, if the users click the confirm button twice on the paypal page, two requests are coming back to my Struts 1 action and due to this system is throwing an application exception for the user and at the same time payment is deducting from credit card. I want to accept the first request and stop the second request. please let me know if anyone faced and solved this issue.

Comment: Please include the relevant portions of your code. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the concept of a token. Note, this is not a fully working code solution.

1. Create and save a transaction token in your Action class that loads your JSP form

   `saveToken(request)`
2. Check if the token is valid in your action that would process the form submit

   `if (isTokenValid(request, true)) {
       processRequest();
   } else {
       return mapping.findForward("invalidToken");
   }`

Here is some more info on tokens in Struts1:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/archive/trunk/struts-doc-1.1/api/org/apache/struts/util/TokenProcessor.html